# How do I overwrite node title for specific content type?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to add a chapter tag (§) in front of a title for content type 'ABC' in a Drupal 7 site.

I tried the following:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-full';
  }
  //watchdog("mytheme_preprocess_node", 'items %items', array('%items' => print_r($variables['node'], true)));
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type=='abc') {
    $node->title = 'this is a test' . $node->title; 
    $variables['node'] = $node;
    watchdog("mytheme", 'items %items', array('%items' => print_r($variables['node'], true)));
  }
}
```

I did see the message output in the log, however updated title is not showing up on the site.

Comment: Is your theme picking up on the preprocess function? If you've justed added it you may need to clear the cache.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but you don't need to do `$variables['node'] = $node;` the variable is already equal to the node.

Comment: I suggest you use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module for debugging (and for other tasks too), and some of its functions like `dsm()`, etc., instead of logging everything using `watchdog()`. By the way, another really useful module is [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer), but it's rather useful for theming (not surprisingly). Anyway, +1 for your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every implementation of `hook_preprocess_node()` made from a module (or a theme) is executed after [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), which contains the following code:

```
  $variables['node_url']  = url($uri['path'], $uri['options']);
  $variables['title']     = check_plain($node->title);
  $variables['page']      = $variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($node);
```

`template_preprocess_node()` is the preprocess function executed from the Node module, which is the module that defines `theme_node()`.

The template file is then using `$title` for the page title.

```
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

If you want to change the value for title, you should change the value of `$title`, in your preprocess function.

The execution order of preprocess functions is explained in the documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7). In that documentation "HOOK" is a placeholder for the type of the preprocess function, e.g. "node," "html," and "page."
Between the rendering engine used for the theme, a module, and the currently set theme, the preprocess function implemented from the theme is the last one to be called. This helps if there is another module that alters the title, and you want to use the one set from the theme.

What I reported is also valid for Drupal 6.

Comment: Thank you. Changing $variables['title'] in mytheme_preprocess_node solved my problem