# How to override node content in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

So I see in the archives how to override a node's $title ([How do I overwrite node title for specific content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/how-do-i-overwrite-node-title-for-specific-content-type)), but how would I override the node's content in Drupal 7? I see that Drupal 7 no longer uses $vars['content'], which was really handy in Drupal 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7 the content is in $content.

See node.tpl.php

```
<?php print render($content); ?>
```

The $content definition:

> An array of node items. Use render($content) to print them all, or
>   print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use
>   hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing
>   of a given element.